# Send Raspberry pi sensor data to remote elasticsearch via python `request` code

Tags: python, json, python-requests

**Sensor Data --> Raspberry Pi --- (send sensors data via `requests` Python Code) ---> remote server (Elasticsearch)**

**Target** is sending received sensor data to elasticsearch via `request` python module.

**Question:** When I use this code: `data = '{"TempA":"23"}'`, the post request work and document of elasticsearch is being updated as shown below:

`{"_index":"report","_type":"_doc",{"TempA":"23"}`

But when I changed the code to: `data = {"TempA": mens}`, to get value of sensor directly, it does not work and document of elasticsearch does not update. (This is my python code which receives data from sensor and put the value of sensor in "mens".)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
from SX127x.LoRa import *
from SX127x.board_config import BOARD
import requests

BOARD.setup()
BOARD.reset()
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

class mylora(LoRa):

    def __init__(self, verbose=False):
        super(mylora, self).__init__(verbose)
        self.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)
        self.set_dio_mapping([0] * 6)

    def on_rx_done(self):
        self.clear_irq_flags(RxDone=1)
        payload = self.read_payload(nocheck=True)
        mens=bytes(payload).decode("utf-8",'ignore')
        print(mens)
        data = {"TempA":mens}
        response = requests.post('http://192.168.100.125:9200/report/_doc/customer505', headers=headers, data=data)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.reset_ptr_rx()
        self.set_mode(MODE.RXCONT)

    def start(self):
        while True:
            self.reset_ptr_rx()
            self.set_mode(MODE.RXCONT) # Receiver mode
            while True:
                pass;
```

Comment: Why would you want to use `curl` as oppose to something like `requests`?

Comment: Hi @FelipeFaria, Just I wanna send my sensor data to my elasticsearch. I can not use mqtt because I couldnt have static IP for publisher. So after some googling, I found curl. So, Do you have any idea?

Comment: I think you might be a bit confused on what [`curl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) is for. `cURL` is a command-line tool that allows you to send web requests such as [`GET`, `POST`, etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) to IPs or website on the internet. A Python module like `requests` is _made to allow you to do this exact same function directly through Python_. In your very code you have a `requests.post` function call, which does the exact thing both question (1) and (2) asks about.

Comment: Where is says `data = '{"TempA":"10", "TempB":"20", "TempC":"30"}'`, you would have to change that to `data = {"tempA": sensor.var1, "tempB": sensor.var2, "tempC": sensor.var3}` where `sensor.varX` is an `int` that represents information outputted by your sensors.

Comment: Thanks for describing concepts. I changed it as you told, `data = {"soilA": mens, "customer_id":"customer555"}` . mens is information outputted by sensors. But unfortunatelly, it doesnt work. @FelipeFaria

Comment: Can you clarify what the question is? What's going on with curl, in the end?

Comment: Also, your class name isn't following style conventions, and asterisk/`*` imports are a bad idea.

Comment: Hey @AMC, Just I wanna send information outputted from sensors to elasticsearch via "request" python module. Now, when I change the code according the solution that FelipeFaria said, Unfortunately, it did not work.

Comment: If you changed the code then edit your question so we can see what you're actually running. What does _it did not work_ mean, exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AMC. I edited the code. It does not work mean: when I change the value of Temp A to received value from sensor as FelipeFaria said, it does not get data from sensor and also update data of document on elasticsearch. Is it clear?

Comment: @RezaAbdinezhad Right, I was hoping for something more specific. At which point do things stop working as expected, for example?

Comment: Just I updated the question and code. I hope to be clear @AMC

Comment: Why the `while true: pass;`, by the way? Why the semicolon, too?

Comment: `while true: pass;` code is related to transceiver module sample code and its working. my question is about upper part.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for comments. After some googling, I found the solution. The key point was `json=params` and `params` instead of `data`. Changes are as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
from SX127x.LoRa import *
from SX127x.board_config import BOARD
import requests
import json

BOARD.setup()
BOARD.reset()
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

class mylora(LoRa):

    def __init__(self, verbose=False):
        super(mylora, self).__init__(verbose)
        self.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)
        self.set_dio_mapping([0] * 6)

    def on_rx_done(self):
        self.clear_irq_flags(RxDone=1)
        payload = self.read_payload(nocheck=True)
        mens=bytes(payload).decode("utf-8",'ignore')
        print(mens)
        url = 'http://192.168.100.125:9200/report/_doc/customer600'
        params = {'soilA': mens, 'customer_id': 'customer600'}
        r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=params)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.reset_ptr_rx()
        self.set_mode(MODE.RXCONT)
```